# TreeView: can't set SelectedNode

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have implemented a navigation system where the user can click on Next and Back arrow buttons (like in a browser session) in order to navigate through treenodes.

```
Private Sub TSB_Back_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TSB_Back.Click
        Try
            If CurrentNode?.Previous?.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                TV.SelectedNode = CurrentNode.Previous.Value
                TV.SelectedNode.EnsureVisible()
                CurrentNode = CurrentNode.Previous
                If CurrentNode.Previous Is Nothing Then TSB_Back.Enabled = False
                TSB_Next.Enabled = True
            End If
        Catch
        End Try
End Sub
```

However after I click on the Back arrow, the SelectedNode is set to treeview.Nodes(0). There is no exception thrown but if I manually evaluate in Debug mode the expression `TV.SelectedNode = CurrentNode.Previous.Value` I get this weird error:

> error BC30452: Operator '=' is not defined for types 'TreeNode' and 'TreeNode'.

I have tried adding BeginEdit and EndEdit, but that didn't make any change. Is this a bug? Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Is that a custom class that inherits from Treenode or something? I'm a bit confused because .Previous isn't a member of the TreeNode class in any .net framework I've ever used, and unless you've overridden the operators, = is certainly defined for a TreeNode and the SelectedNode can be set that way

Comment: `CurrentNode` is of type `LinkedListNode(Of TreeNode)` and it points to a member of a `LinkedList(Of TreeNode)` named `NavigatedNodes`. `NavigatedNodes` is populated as we navigate nodes. None of those classes are custom classes, so there shouldn't be any problem.